# Prevent unrelated mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say I have 2 php scripts which runs from distinct pages (distinct urls). Take a look:

Script 1:

```
<?php
// 15:43:00 - Connect to database.
// 15:43:00 - Mysql query: "SELECT user_data FROM users WHERE user_id = 5"
// 15:43:00 - sleep(5)
// 15:43:05 - Mysql query: "INSERT INTO another_table (table_user_data, table_user_id) VALUES ($user_data, 5)"
```

Script 2:

```
<?php
// 15:43:03 - Connect to database.
// 15:43:03 - Mysql query: "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = 5"
```

I hope you saw the time. So, my question is:

The script 2 will wait until script 1 is successfully excecuted or it will run the query and delete the user ?

If it will delete the user, then how should I insert the row into table "another_table" as mysql `INSERT` syntax doesn't accept `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: While it doesn't change your problem, just a note: `insert` has two versions: `insert () values ()` and `insert () select ...`. In the latter case, you *can* use `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script 2 will not wait for Script 1 to finish. It is called a race condition in programing.

Do deal with this race condition in MySQL, you can add a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to `another_table.table_user_id` to reference `users.user_id`. In which case an insert into `another_table` will fail if the `user_id` does not exist in the `users` table at any given time.